# In which cases, there is no continuous map from A onto B?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

(a) $A=[0,1]\cup[2,3], B=\{1,2\}$

(b) $A=(0,1), B=[0,1]$

(c) $A=\mathbb{Q}, B=\mathbb{Q}$

(d) $A=(0,1)\cup(2,3), B=\{1,3\}$

It was clear for (b) as it was already asked numerous times on this site.

For (c), I took identity map.

For (d), We can send $(0,1)$ to $1$ and $(2,3)$ to $3$. Map is clearly onto and into a discrete space. It is continuous as inverse image of each singelton is open.

**What about (a)?**

Comment: @phuclv changing letters to numbers invalidated existing answers.

Comment: For (1) use the same idea as for (4)

Comment: I belive Mathaman got 1 and 2 confused?  And is actually asking about 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a) $x\mapsto \begin{cases}1&x<\sqrt2\\2&x>\sqrt 2\end{cases}$

b) $x\mapsto \frac{1+\sin 42x}2$

c) $x\mapsto x$

d) $x\mapsto \lceil x\rceil$

Comment: nice formula for b).

Comment: How do you come up with $b$. Can you share the secret. I mean how to think? I will be thankful

Comment: @MathamanTopologius How to come up with that kind of formula? Well, we're looking for a function whose image is $[0, 1]$. Do we know of any functions with that kind of image? Well, the sine function has $[-1, 1]$ as its image, and that's close enough to be usable. We can easily modify it so that its image is $[0, 1]$: that's $(\sin x + 1)/2$. But is the image still $[0, 1]$ when you restrict the domain to $(0, 1)$? No, it's not, so we need to do something about that. The image *is* still $[0, 1]$ if you restrict the domain to, say, $(0, 42)$. (continued in next comment...)

Comment: So after you have $(\sin x + 1)/2$ with its domain restricted to $(0, 42)$, you just have to compress the function down so that its domain fits into $(0, 1)$. That's $(\sin 42 x + 1)/2$.

Answer (score 4):

a) goes the same as (d): map each interval to a separate point.

Note that $[0,1]$ is closed and open in $[0,1] \cup [2,3]$.